# Create Telnet connections to multiple servers and log the welcome messages

Tags: filezilla, telnet, plink

I need to remotely determine what FileZilla Server version is installed on a large number of computers .

I know that if I initialise a Telnet connection to a FZ server, I will get a response that includes the server version, and the connection will then hang until terminated with **quit**, **Ctrl+C**, or by killing the process.

What I'm looking for is a way to iterate through the list of servers, make the Telnet connection to each one, and record the message with the server version in a file.
If there's a more elegant way of getting that information, I'm all ears - but this is the best that I've been able to come up with.

I've tried searching for answers, but most scenarios just need to check for connection (ie is the server online), and thus test-Connection etc works.

**What I have so far:**

- Using plink, the puTTY CMD interface (so I have a scriptable Telnet client)
- Using Powershell, as I know it better than windows CMD scripting, but am open to answers in other languages.

My primary issue is getting the response to be saved somewhere.
Plink opens a new session when it connects, and I've been seriously struggling to save the response to the main script logfile (or at all)

This invokes a new plink session but I just cannot get it to send the output to a file.

```
MyPC>Start-Process 'plink.exe' -ArgumentList '-telnet', '$IP', '-P', '$PORT'
```

Gives me this:

```
220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.43 beta
220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
```

However, the code below does not send that message to the file. I've tried it with `2>` and `3>` as well in case it's sent to the error stream or similar but no joy - it always just creates an empty file.

```
Start-Process 'plink.exe' -ArgumentList '-telnet', '$IP', '-P', '$PORT' > C:\Temp\testps2.txt
```

I'm either missing something mindbogglingly simple or it's one of those things that seems simple in principal, but is very complex to do in practice.

My second step would be to automatically close the new sessions after they opens (and after capturing the welcome message) - but until I can capture the welcome message,there's not much point looking further.

Any help or thoughts gratefully appreciated; I'm at a bit of a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although FTP was originally Telnet-based, it isn't *really* a "Telnet connection". For all intents and purposes, it's a very generic ASCII-over-TCP protocol that only has a few similarities to Telnet.

(The real reason you can still connect to FTP servers with a Telnet client is because all Telnet handshaking happens in-line *and* because your Telnet client disables most of it when connecting to other ports than the standard 23.)

So it would be easier to treat the problem as one of collecting banners from TCP servers, not Telnet servers, as then you can use the regular TCP socket support provided by .NET (all of which is available to PowerShell). In other words, rather than forking a subprocess, you can stay entirely within PowerShell (or C# via Add-Type, not that that should be needed).

I found a StackOverflow [example script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59390759/49849) that does something very similar (and deals with FTP, in fact), so I'd start from that – remove the "Read-Host" bits; tweak the loop to collect as much data as available before breaking out (optionally send a `` QUIT`r`n ``); put it all in a PS function.